# Is there a way to find all the global styles that apply to a web page?

Tags: javascript, css

As a company, we use components (Angular, Vue and React) to build our applications, but we still have a good number of global styles that we inherited from our legacy app.

eg:

```
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

Will apply to any element anywhere on the page that has a class of active.

Is there a way, in the browser, to generate a list of all the global (i.e. non-namespaced) style rules that apply to a page, bearing in mind that these might be present inside of third-party libraries, or other miscellaneous legacy JavaScripts?

Comment: @NikhilGhuse please read the question first?

Comment: Could this help you, by any chance? http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/csssteal-chrome-extension-that-extracts-css

Comment: You could try `document.styleSheets`

Comment: When you say not namespaced, do you just mean selectors that don't contain names from other libraries? Or do you really mean selectors that are not `<style scoped>` or `@namespace` ?

Comment: @skyline - It's a good question, and I don't have a good answer. We have a variety of different component oriented frameworks in production, and also a load of legacy SASS. Distinguishing between the two is a non-trivial problem, which is why I'm throwing it open to the floor. I think the current best solution is just to get all the styles, sort by selector length, and then go through by hand.

Comment: @sjahan - That's a pretty cool Chrome extension.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-namespaced"? Can you please clarify or give an example for?

Comment: @evilReiko - Please see skyline's question. I have a variety of component oriented frameworks in production. Those styles are encapsulated using a variety of techniques, including BEM, ViewEncapsulation, SASS Modules, JSX-CSS, etc. The result is a running DOM full of CSS. I need to sort out the styles that are nicely encapsulated to a component, from the ones that are generic. It's very much not a trivial problem, and I don't think there's a simple solution, which is why I'm throwing it open to the collective.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only option for evaluating the current page's CSS styles is to use `document.styleSheets`. It will return a list of `CSSStyleSheet`s.

You will want to focus on `document.styleSheets[n].cssRules`, where `n` equals which stylesheet you want to evaluate. That will give you a list of all the styles applied by that stylesheet. Each stylesheet will have a `cssText` and a `selectorText` property.

If you just want to loop through to find which styles are 'non-namespaced' you should probably just use the `selectorText` properties.

Here is some [more information on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) about `document.styleSheets`.

Here is an example (press 'Run code snippet' to see results):

```js
var selectors = [];

var sheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets);

sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
  // Only Stylesheets from a same-origin domain expose `cssRules` for security reasons
  try {
    var rules = Array.from(sheet.cssRules);
    rules.forEach(function(rule) {
      selectors.push(rule.selectorText);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Do something with external stylesheets if you want
  }
});

console.log(selectors);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Stylesheets</title>
  <style>
    .hello-world {
      background: url(none.gif);
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Won't work as it is not a same-original stylesheet -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .foo {
      background: url(none.gif)
    }
    
    .bar {
      background: url(none.gif);
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @superluminary This seems like it should be the accepted solution. Is there something this answer doesn't address for your question?

Comment: Nope, this is the top answer. A bounty gets featured shortly before it expires, so I usually leave it open until the end to get the most value for everyone.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this might help, but try it. If you're using Chrome, try this:

1. Inspect (to open Developer tools) > Audits (tab) > Select "Audit Present Stage" > Click "Run"

[image]

2. Chrome will display all unused CSS rules.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Also worth trying: Inspect (to open Developers tools) > click on the 3 vertical dots next to "Console" tab > Coverage.

It will show list of CSS/JS files loaded, and it will highlight which lines are used (green) and not used (red). [Read More](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this script to get all the selectors form stylesheets internal and external

```js
for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
   var s = document.styleSheets[i];
   for(var j=0; s.cssRules && j<s.cssRules.length; j++) {
      var c = s.cssRules[j];
      console.log(c.selectorText);
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.test{color:red;}
</style>
```

To get final applied CSS properties of Element try something like this with Javascript

By using `getComputedStyle()` you can get exact computed final style applied on the element.

> The `Window.getComputedStyle()` method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.
>
> The returned style is a live CSSStyleDeclaration object, which updates itself automatically when the element's style is changed.

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
var background = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("background-color"); 
var color = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("color"); 
console.log(background);
console.log(color);
```

```css
.active{background-color:blue;color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="active">
some text
</div>
```

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 3):

```
    var rulesArr = [];
    var styles = document.styleSheets;

    for ( i=0; i<styles.length; i++ ){
      //iterate styleSheets.

      if(styles[i].rules){
      //Must be a rule to continue.

        for ( x=0; x<styles[i].rules.length; x++ ){
        //iterate rules, an object in styleSheets.

        rulesArr.push(styles[i].rules[x].selectorText);
        //appends selectorText i.e. css class names to our variable.
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(rulesArr);
```